# How to get onPause in the override methods in Android Studio

Tags: android

I am new to android development, and I was learning about the life cycles of an activity.
I was trying to override the onPause method. But I searched everywhere, updated IDE, plugins and any updates necessary but I still could not find it. All the others are there(onCreate, onStart, onResume, onStop and onDestroy) only one am missing is the onPause.[image]

Any help on how to get it.

[it shows an error when I try to write the code manually](https://i.stack.imgur.com/GCF0o.png)

Comment: Paste the code for your Activity into your question please

Comment: how about posting a [mcve] instead of screenshots?

Answer (score 1):

This is the signature:

```
@Override
    protected void onPause() {
        super.onPause();
    }
```

Also, in Android Studio you can press Ctrl+O to give you a list of all override-able methods and you can search there the one you need. Of course, this is only valid inside Activity type class

Comment: yes I did the Ctrl-O but onPause was not in the list. That the image I showed in the question. And when I try to wrote the code manually I get an error.

Comment: Are you doing this in an Activity class?

Comment: yes. I am doing it in MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity

Comment: As you can see in the Docs: https://developer.android.com/reference/androidx/appcompat/app/AppCompatActivity onPause is not part of the AppCompatActivity

Answer (score 0):

you can preview all methods that you can override by click ctrl+o, try search onpause (type the whole word) after dialog is opened you will found it

Answer (score 0):

onPause is an android life cycle method. You can put it on Activity extended classes. If you are going to use onPause in regular class (non-activity), You can't just put this onPause override method.

To generate the onPause override method. press CMD+N (Mac) or ALT+Insert (Windows).

Also if onPause already in your class in the list you can't find it again!.

You can implement the override method manually by including,

```
@Override
protected void onPause() {
  super.onPause();
}
```